# Include console app in GTK app

Tags: python, vim, gtk, glade, gtkbuilder

I'd like to create an application similar to gvim, so that I'll have gtk application with console application included (in my case, it's vim or any other console text editor)

What is the best way to do this?
If there is a way, how can I comunicate with this console editor from GUI?

I should be runnable on linux, but I'd really appreciate if it works on windows and other systems as well

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gvim isn't a gtk wrapper for vim. It is a version of vim that uses gtk+ widgets instead of stdin and stdout.

You can add smooth gtk+ support to other programs by modifying their source code, but you'll have to implement the gui from scratch.

Alternatively, you could embed a [VTE](http://developer-old.gnome.org/vte/unstable/) terminal widget in your gtk program. But I don't think that's what you are looking for.